# Compare image segmentation with ground-truth with different colors

Tags: computer-vision, metrics, scikit-image

I've got two images I would like to compare: one is a ground-truth image and the other is the result of applying a segmentation technique on the image used as a source for the ground-truth.

The problem I'm facing is that even if the segmentation made by the technique is correct in terms of isolation of shapes, colors are assigned without following the same ground-truth criterion for the manual segmentation, thus leading to a worse comparison.

I also dispaly here the code used with cv and skimage libraries (first image is the original, the second is the segmented one and the third the ground-truth):

```
img = cv.imread(raw)  #import image
gt_img = cv.imread(GT) #import image
img = cv.cvtColor(raw, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB) #convert it to RGB
gt_img = cv.cvtColor(GT, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)#convert it to RGB

labels1 = segmentation.slic(img, compactness=100, n_segments=500,
                            start_label=1,  max_num_iter=20, channel_axis = -1)
out1 = color.label2rgb(labels1, img, kind='avg', bg_label=0)
g = graph.rag_mean_color(img, labels1, mode='similarity')
labels1_NCUT = graph.cut_normalized(labels1, g)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Is there any metric that can allow me to perform a comparison between the GT image and the segmented one solving the issue of different colors assignment?

Comment: I think your question does not make any sense, because segmentation is not evaluated using "colors", but with class indices or probability vectors.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy thanks for the feedback: do you have any python resources you could suggest in order to evaluate the segmented image i obtained with a ground truth one, using indices/prob. vectors?

Answer (score 1):

scikit-image provides a variety of metrics you can use for evaluation of segmentations in the [`skimage.metrics`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.metrics.html) module. The [variation of information](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.metrics.html#skimage.metrics.variation_of_information) is a personal favorite of mine. There is a [short example](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_metrics.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-segmentation-plot-metrics-py) in the scikit-image docs discussing variation of information and adapted rand error.